# jmeter shows "500 Internal Server Error" with UnmarshalException in viewresulttree

Tags: exception, jmeter

Out of nowhere, jmeter started failing 100% for my normal web service requests. Upon further analysis found that, at server empty request is received. Attached viewresultstree listener with all flags ON and found below error

> <?xml
>   version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><ns2:Fault
>   xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot;
>   xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><faultcode>ns2:Server</faultcode><faultstring>javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag &lt;/Client&gt;; expected
>   &lt;/EOF&gt;.  at [row,col {unknown-source}]:
>   [24,16]]</faultstring></ns2:Fault>

I can say that there is no XML parsing exception. Can someone please help me on this weird jmeter behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it was with the input file. somehow the input file turned into empty file which was providing EOF for input parameter and hence the request was being treated as ended when this first EOF appeared at server HTTP endpoint.

Fixing this input data file resolved this issue to me. :)